# Multiply list with binary

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I am trying to create a powerset by multiplying binary counter with array to get

```
Value of Counter            Subset
    000                    -> Empty set
    001                    -> a
    010                    -> b
    011                    -> ab
    100                    -> c
    101                    -> ac
    110                    -> bc
    111                    -> abc
```

My code:

```
A = ['a','b','c']
n = len(A)
for i in range(2**n):
    print format(i,'b') and A
```

I get all the outputs as `['a','b','c']` . Is there a different way to do the print statement to get the required result.

Comment: What exactly is `format(i,'b') and A` supposed to do? Filter `A`?

Comment: It doesn't work I still get all outputs as ['a','b','c']

Comment: @tobias_k Yes, it's supposed to filter it.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `format(i,'b') and A` is not the same as "bitwise-and of the binary number `i` with the elements of list `A`". `X and Y` is logical-and and is interpreted as `Y if X else X`, thus you always get `A` as a result.

You can use a list comprehension, checking the bitwise `&` of `2**i` (`i` being the current index) and the running number. Also, no explicit conversion to binary is needed.

```
>>> [[e for i, e in enumerate(A) if 2**i & x] for x in range(2**n)]
[[], ['a'], ['b'], ['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
d = {0b1: 'a', 0b10: 'b', 0b100: 'c'}
for i in range(0b1000):
    s = ''
    for k, v in d.items():
        if i & k:
             s += v
    print s
```

Edit: Some explination

So you're trying to associate `'a', 'b', 'c'` to `1, 2 and 4` respectively. To do this I used the dictionary above (using binary literals for clarity).

Then, looping through all 0 <= i < 8, you can see if there is a `1` at the relevant position using the `&` operator.

e.g. is there a `1` at the second position from the right: `0b00 & 0b10 == 0b01 & 0b10 == 0` is false, whereas `0b10 & 0b10 == 0b11 & 0b10 != 0`is true.

Comment: some explanation would be welcome, even if this seems to be a valid answer.

Comment: note that `s = ''.join(v for k, v in d.items() if i & k)` is way more performant & pythonic

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Considering the question asked, I wouldn't start throwing list comprehensions at the asker...

Answer (score 0):

You cant use bitwise operation between a string and a list.

I tried the following way.

```
A = ['a','b','c']
n = len(A)
for i in range(2**n):
    s = format(i,'b')[::-1]
    print(''.join( (A[j] for j in range(len(s)) if s[j]=='1' )))
```

Comment: The result is somewhat equivalent, but this will add `a` to `100`, not to `001`.